# Is there any plan for ISRO to reach Venus?

Tags: launch, isro, venus

After successfully completing the placement of the Mangalyaan into orbit, is there any plan for ISRO to launch a spacecraft to Venus ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There were plans for a Venus mission in 2015](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2012-02-17/hyderabad/31070866_1_venus-mission-chandrayaan-1-isro) ([alternate article](http://www.asianscientist.com/topnews/isro-indian-mission-to-planet-venus-2012/))

> An Indian scientific mission to Venus is being considered by the space
>   community. This was announced by M S Anurup of Isro at the 17th
>   National Space Science Symposium which has been jointly organised by
>   Isro and Sri Venkateshwara University.
>
> According to Anurup, a preliminary study had indicated that if this
>   mission gets the go ahead and depending upon the orbital parameters,
>   it could be launched on May 20, 2015 arriving in Venus in October
>   2015.

I don't see any indication of this mission being scrapped, but I don't see any further announcements either. I think it's pretty OK to assume that it is still ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, it should be RISAT mission - ie. the spacecraft that would be sent to Venus would be similar to the radar imaging satellite RISAT-1 which India put in orbit around Earth. Otherwise, Venus' thick clouds make surface observation impossible.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to add a link to the source that you mention? Without it, we can only guess what article you have read and its credibility. Was it perchance 
[ISRO Announces Preliminary Study On Indian Mission To Venus](http://www.asianscientist.com/2012/02/topnews/isro-indian-mission-to-planet-venus-2012/) article in AsianScientist that's already linked to in Manishearth's answer?